# "No Instance of type variable R exist so that Observable conforms to Observable" Error when updating to RxJava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to make a call to API using `retrofit and rxJava`. The code below seems to work well when using `RxJava 1`, but once I updated to `RxJava 2` I am getting this error:

**Error :**

> No Instance of type variable R exist so that Observable conforms to
>   Observable

**Api**

```
Observable<HttpResult<List<Article>>> getList(@Query("key")String key);
```

Api request done here, and this is where I get this error inside `.map` operator

```
Observable cache=providers.getList().map(new HttpRsltFunc<List<Article>>());
```

**Result class model :**

```
private  class HttpRsltFunc<T> implements Func1<HttpResult<T>, T> {
       @Override
       public T call(HttpResult<T> httpResult) {   
           return httpResult.getData();
       }
   }
```

**Edit :**

When importing `rx.Observable` instead of `io.reactivex.Observable` the code works just fine.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe define it as `Observable<List<Article>> cache`

Comment: tried that, same issue :/

Comment: Thank you for adding the Edit. That fixed my problem as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because rxjava2 migrated to their own [functional interfaces](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#functional-interfaces), so you need to implement different interface instead of `Func1`.

And don't forget to update your retrofit adapter to rxjava2 version:
`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:latest.version'`

Comment: Yeah that was the issue and the fact that I didn't use the appropriate RxCache to work with the new RxJava.Thanks.